# Compiling Sphinx with iPython doc error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'worksheets'"

Tags: ipython, python-sphinx

When compiling documentation using Sphinx, I got the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'worksheets'`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because you don't have the most recent iPython installed. You probably installed it with `sudo apt-get install ipython`, but you should upgrade using `sudo pip install ipython --upgrade` and then making sure that the previous installation was removed by running `sudo apt-get remove ipython`.